# Cordova command-line build fails in /tmp on Mac

Tags: ios, cordova, linker

I get a linker error building a brand-new PhoneGap app from the command line. It creates a bunch of files, and if I open the created `.xcodeproj` in Xcode, it builds just fine. So what's wrong with my command-line environment?

```
$ phonegap create /tmp/buildtest-ios
$ cd /tmp/buildtest-ios
$ phonegap -V build ios
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] Checking iOS requirements...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling iOS...
[phonegap] Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "ios"
[phonegap] Compiling app on platform "ios" via command "/private/tmp/buildtest-ios/platforms/ios/cordova/build" 
   [error] An error occurred while building the ios project.** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /private/tmp/buildtest-ios/platforms/ios/build/emulator/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld normal i386
(1 failure)
```

If I run the offending `Ld` command myself from the command line, I get "file not found". Does that mean the compiler failed and the linker error is just a red herring?

This is PhoneGap 3.3.0-0.18.0 on Mac OS X 10.9. I can create and build an Android app with this installation, no trouble. I get the exact same behavior if I use `cordova` directly. I've tried it on two Macs with the same symptom.

Comment: Check if all the path variables are set correctly

Comment: @Purus Which path variables? Can you link to docs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally discovered the answer using the `cordova` command-line tools. Cordova has a `-d` flag which is way more verbose than PhoneGap's `-V` flag. The linker was failing with a bunch of errors like

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVTimer in:
    /private/tmp/buildtest-ios/platforms/ios/build/emulator/libCordova.a(CDVTimer.o)
    /tmp/buildtest-ios/platforms/ios/build/emulator/libCordova.a(CDVTimer.o)
```

Note that `/tmp` on Mac is a symlink to `/private/tmp`, so these are pointing to the same file. No wonder they're duplicate symbols! So why is it trying to include the same file twice?

I tried creating a new test project in an empty folder `/private/my-new-tmp2/buildtest-ios`. Building it failed with the same error. So apparently something is weird with Cordova's iOS projects and the `Ld` linker in the `/private` directory on Mac OS X 10.9, and I'm the only person who's ever tried this. (As I said, building for Android works fine.)

In case someone else ever runs into the same problem, the solution is to build the project in `/Users/me/some/directory` rather than anywhere in `/tmp` or `/private`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because your framework references are corrupted or point to nowhere. In the left of XCode under 'Frameworks' and 'Resources' try re-adding anything you added yourself. Chances are with Cordova its a plugin SDK you are using that has been updated or deleted.

Comment: I'm not using Xcode. I literally typed those three commands from the command line to create a new project and build it - no plugins or anything else custom whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while placing my project under /var/www/PROJECT on mac. I was getting the duplicate errors along with "**`../cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 65`**".

I was getting the duplicate errors because /var/www/ is also /private/var/www/

Solution was to move my project as described above to /Users/username/some-other-dir/...

I then ran `phonegap run ios` and all worked!